# Advantage of function pointers over flags

Tags: c, callback, function-pointers

Lets say for eg., I have a function called **int compute ( int x1, int x2, int (* op) (int, int) )**, which takes as an argument a function pointer to a function that does some arithmetic operation

```
int add (int a1, int a2)
{
    return (a1 + a2);
}
int mul (int s1, int s2)
{
    return (s1 * s2);
}
int compute (int x1, int x2, int (* op) (int, int) )
{
    return ( op (x1, x2) );
}
main()
{
    int result;
    int op1, op2;
    op1 = 4;
    op2 = 5;
    result = compute (op1, op2, &add());
    result = compute (op1, op2, &mul());
}
```

Instead of all this function pointer stuff, I can as well use flags as argument instead function pointer to achieve the same.

```
int compute (int x1, int x2, int opFlag)
{
    if ( opFlag == 1 )
        return ( add (x1, x2); );
    if ( opFlag == 2)
        return ( mul (x1, x2); );
    return 1;
}

main()
{
    int result;
    int op1, int op2;

    op1 = 4;
    op2 = 5;

    result = compute (op1, op2, 1);
    result = compute (op1, op2, 2);
}
```

Now the question is, what are the (ad/disad)vantages of the **"function pointer"** approach vs **"simple flag approach"** in terms of efficiency, code size, portability, readability etc., ?

Comment: If you use flags and if you want to add more functions, you'll have to edit the code to add more `if` clauses.

Comment: With a function pointer, you can pass other algorithms without changing or recompiling `compute`.

Comment: You gain reusability with function pointers. `Compute( )` can be placed in a library and distributed to other users without needing to be updated to support new operations.

Comment: Are you asking about in general or in this particular case?  In general, how would you implement things like `qsort` or `bsearch` with flags?

Comment: The line `result = compute (op1, op2, &add());` contains an error and should not compile (gcc says `erreur: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand`. The line should be `result = compute (op1, op2, add);` wich takes the address of `add()` as needed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what are the (ad/disad)vantages of the "function pointer" approach vs "simple flag approach" in terms of efficiency,

Fewer calls may be faster. On many CPUs function calls come at a noticeable cost when you do a lot of them.

> code size,

Fewer functions may be smaller as you don't have the duplicated overhead of the function prolog and epilog code.

> portability,

Does not apply as long as your code is correct, doesn't suffer from undefined behavior and does not depend on implementation-defined/specific behavior.

> readability

May be subjective. Often times, fewer abstraction layers and fewer indirections are easier to understand than more.

> etc., ?

Define `etc`.

Answer (score 0):

what about when you want to add a new operation?

Function pointers let you (or your libraries future customers) do that without changing the compute function